# Full page WebView screenshot doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android

I'm tring to take screenshot of a WebView with its invisible parts. When height of the WebView is too long (E.g. 20000 px) I'm facing a problem that bottom part of the screenshot(E.g. 7000 px) has a solid color.

This is my code:

```
Picture picture = webWiew.capturePicture();

Bitmap b = null;

try {
    b = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(),
    picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    picture.draw(c);

catch (OutOfMemoryError outOfMemoryError) {

    }
```

and this is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: how you are calling above code in which method?

Answer (score 0):

Inflating content into a WebView takes up memory. Depending on the implementation, it will inflate different amounts of data outside of the screen to make scrolling feel smooth for the user.

So, your problem is that **the data for the last (Solid color) part simply is not there** :-)

You may check the documentation for WebView to see if it is possible to make the preload offset unlimited, but I doubt it, as it would lead to lots of OutOfMemoryErrors.

---

EDIT:

Also, .capturePicture() seems to be deprecated. Please try the below snippet:

```
Picture picture = webWiew.capturePicture(); //Just to get real content dimensions, you can later look for another source of them

Bitmap b = null;

try {
    b = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(),
    picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    webView.onDraw(c); //This changed

catch (OutOfMemoryError outOfMemoryError) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a good perspective but my problem is not about it. If I scroll down to bottom of the WebView and take screenshot at that time, exactly the same scenario happens again.

Comment: With exactly the same output? Or this time the solid color is at top?

Comment: With exactly the same output. Solid color is at the bottom again.

Comment: WebView doesn't have a draw method

Comment: My bad, it is onDraw()

Comment: It doesn't have onDraw() as well, did you mean onDrawForeground()

Answer (score 0):

You should be override picture.draw() method

Comment: How exactly do this?